# Docker-Steam cant launch more often Game than 5 Time

Tags: wine, games, virtualization, steam, ulimit

I use this github Project: https://github.com/webanck/docker-wine-steam
to run the Game in the container.

It works really fine and i can launch the game multiple times.
But in the 6th container the game wont start.

The Problem must be some settings because my Hardware would be good enough to run more then 10 Containers.

What i saw when i tried to fix the problem that docker uses x11 to forward the graphics.
I alredy tried to set the Limit ressources to unlimited but it did not work.

Im not really experienced in Linux, i just know some basics.

So what could it be ?

Comment: to clarify, you're trying to launch the same game in 6+ different containers simultaneously?

Comment: yes exactly that